# Calculating Pi Using Taylor Series

Tags: python, for-loop, pi, taylor-series

I am trying to calculate the value for Pi using Taylor Series. Below is the code that I have, but when I run the program I get a list of 1's and 0's.

Here is my code:

```
from math import *
import numpy as np

n= 100
x= 1
series = []

for i in range(0,n):
    value = (x**(2*i+1)*(-1)**i)/(2*i+1)
    series.append(value)

print series
```

Comment: As a note, when using range to index a for loop, for memory purposes, it is typically better to use `xrange` rather than `range`.  This link talks about it more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135041/should-you-always-favor-xrange-over-range.  Also, for both `range` and `xrange`, the default lower index is 0 so you can replace `range(0,n)` with `range(n)` (or better `xrange(n)`).

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you all you need to know. You are trying to divide two lists even though you might not think it looks like it. `[]` in Python indicate a list, even though they can be used as brackets in real math. All you have to do is change

```
value = [x**(2*i+1)*(-1)**i]/[2*i+1]
```

to

```
value = (x**(2*i+1)*(-1)**i)/(2*i+1)
```

Comment: Thank you. I realized that immediately after posting.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're running into the [same issue as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685679/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-list-and-list), which is trying to divide one list by another list.  Take a look at the suggestions there and I think you'll find your answer.