# Python Script calculation for list data type returned in Tableau

Tags: python, tabpy

I have a script in python as follows

```
Script_INT("
  testing = _arg1 - _arg2
return test ",
SUM([scores]), SUM([students])
)
```

This gives me an error of

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list and 'list' "
```

When i modify the script to just return 'scores' it prints a number for example 20. and when i edit the script to return  'students' it prints a number for example 10. But when i try to subtract both fields in the script it is not allowing me even though they are coming out as numbers when return individually no calculations.

How can i subtract the two fields to get it to return a number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685679/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-list-and-list)

Answer (score 0):

`_arg1` and `_arg2` are lists so you cannot subtract them. Check the number of values in your lists with `print(len(_arg1))` and `print(len(_arg2))`. If you expect them to have only one value each `testing = _arg1[0] - _arg2[0]` should work.