# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list' when using quiver matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I was running the code below and the following error message came up.

I saw this post which might be potentially a fix to the issue, but I wasn't understanding how this can be applied to solve my issue. Any suggestion is appreciated.

[TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685679/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-list-and-list)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [ 0.5, 0.6, 0.3, 0.2 ]
x2 = [ 0.5, 0.6, 0.3, 0.2 ]
x3 = [ 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6 ]
x4 = [ 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1 ]

y1 = [ 0.7, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2 ]
y2 = [ 0.8, 0.5, 0.9, 0.2 ]
y3 = [ 0.6, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2 ]
y4 = [ 0.8, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5 ]

deltaX1, deltaX2, deltaX3, deltaX4 = [x[1:] - x[:-1] for x in [x1, x2, x3, x4]]
deltaY1, deltaY2, deltaY3, deltaY4 = [y[1:] - y[:-1] for y in [y1, y2, y3, y4]]

line1 = plt.plot(x1, y1,'bo-',label='apple') 
line2 = plt.plot(x2, y2,'go-',label='banana') 
line3 = plt.plot(x3, y3,'ko-',label='orange')
line4 = plt.plot(x4, y4,'ro-',label='tomato') 

arrows1 = plt.quiver(x1[:-1], y1[:-1], deltaX1, deltaY1, scale_units='xy', angles='xy', scale=1)
arrows2 = plt.quiver(x2[:-1], y2[:-1], deltaX2, deltaY2, scale_units='xy', angles='xy', scale=1)
arrows3 = plt.quiver(x3[:-1], y3[:-1], deltaX3, deltaY3, scale_units='xy', angles='xy', scale=1)
arrows4 = plt.quiver(x4[:-1], y4[:-1], deltaX4, deltaY4, scale_units='xy', angles='xy', scale=1)


plt.title("Fruits")
plt.ylabel("Tastiness")
plt.xlabel("Benefit")

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.5, 1),
           bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
```

Error Message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/gf/pvtbdsj96cz1tv7vmn1gq7j40000gn/T/ipykernel_27948/3259319199.py in <module>
     11 y4 = [ 0.8, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5 ]
     12 
---> 13 deltaX1, deltaX2, deltaX3, deltaX4 = [x[1:] - x[:-1] for x in [x1, x2, x3, x4]]
     14 deltaY1, deltaY2, deltaY3, deltaY4 = [y[1:] - y[:-1] for y in [y1, y2, y3, y4]]
     15 

/var/folders/gf/pvtbdsj96cz1tv7vmn1gq7j40000gn/T/ipykernel_27948/3259319199.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     11 y4 = [ 0.8, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5 ]
     12 
---> 13 deltaX1, deltaX2, deltaX3, deltaX4 = [x[1:] - x[:-1] for x in [x1, x2, x3, x4]]
     14 deltaY1, deltaY2, deltaY3, deltaY4 = [y[1:] - y[:-1] for y in [y1, y2, y3, y4]]
     15 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

Comment: What do you expect to get from subtracting a list from a list? `x[1:]` and `x[:-1]` are both lists.

Comment: I think the error message is pretty self-explanatory, but what specifically are you trying to accomplish with `x[1:] - x[:-1]` and `y[1:] - y[:-1]`?

Comment: This is also why a [mcve] is required. This has nothing to do with matplotlib, for example. Also, searching for the error message turns up multiple hits, you just have to read and understand that info first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `numpy.diff(list)` should address the disered output, like this:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [ 0.5, 0.6, 0.3, 0.2 ]
x2 = [ 0.5, 0.6, 0.3, 0.2 ]
x3 = [ 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6 ]
x4 = [ 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1 ]

y1 = [ 0.7, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2 ]
y2 = [ 0.8, 0.5, 0.9, 0.2 ]
y3 = [ 0.6, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2 ]
y4 = [ 0.8, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5 ]

deltaX1, deltaX2, deltaX3, deltaX4 = [numpy.diff(x) for x in [x1, x2, x3, x4]]
deltaY1, deltaY2, deltaY3, deltaY4 = [numpy.diff(y) for y in [y1, y2, y3, y4]]

line1 = plt.plot(x1, y1,'bo-',label='apple') 
line2 = plt.plot(x2, y2,'go-',label='banana') 
line3 = plt.plot(x3, y3,'ko-',label='orange')
line4 = plt.plot(x4, y4,'ro-',label='tomato')
```